# cakephp 1.3 find all now and future up to 5 records total

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-1.3

I'm having trouble getting query to return expected results. Migrating from cakephp 1.1 to 1.3. Currently, my new query does not return any results. Once I get results, I need to limit to 5. Is now() correct within my `$sqlConditions` array? Any suggestions? Thanks for looking.

#### old query cakephp 1.1:

```
function listcomingevents() {
    $conditions="EventsDate.start_date>=now()";
    $this->weekevent="EventsDate.start_date ASC";
    $listcomingeventdata=$this->EventsDate->findAll($conditions,'',$this->weekevent,'5');
    return $listcomingeventdata;
}
```

#### new query cakephp 1.3:

```
function listcomingevents() {
    $sqlConditions = array( "EventsDate.start_date >="=>"now()");

    //remaining code
    $sqlOrderBy = array("EventsDate.start_date asc");
    $sqlParams = array('conditions'=>$sqlConditions,'order'=>$sqlOrderBy);
    $listcomingeventdata=$this->EventsDate->find('all',$sqlParams);
    return $listcomingeventdata;
}
```

also tried:

```
$sqlConditions = array("EventsDate.start_date >="=>"CURDATE()");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `NOW()` expression directly inside the left-hand side, e.g.

```
   $sqlConditions = array( "EventsDate.start_date >= CURDATE()");
```